# Getting Error in webpck cli TypeError: AngularCompilerPlugin is not a constructor

Tags: angular, webpack

**I am getting this error while npm start the error is webpck cli TypeError: AngularCompilerPlugin is not a constructor**

I am running an angular application where I am getting this error even after change to AotPlugin. This is the error.

```
[webpack-cli] Failed to load '/home/gpi0069/Desktop/office/dummy/lithium-clone/webpack.config.js' config
[webpack-cli] TypeError: AngularCompilerPlugin is not a constructor
    at module.exports (/home/gpi0069/Desktop/office/dummy/lithium-clone/config/webpack.common.js:289:13)
    at module.exports (/home/gpi0069/Desktop/office/dummy/lithium-clone/config/webpack.dev.js:37:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/gpi0069/Desktop/office/dummy/lithium-clone/webpack.config.js:17:53)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
    at WebpackCLI.tryRequireThenImport (/home/gpi0069/Desktop/office/dummy/lithium-clone/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:223:30)
```

Here is Package.josn

```
{
    "name": "LITHUM-angular",
    "version": "16.1.0",
    "description": "An Angular project for LITHUM solution",
    "keywords": [
        "angular",
        "angular2",
        "angular4",
        "angular5",
        "webpack",
        "typescript"
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "build:aot:prod": "rm -rf .dist/ compiled && cross-env BUILD_AOT=1 SOURCE_MAP=0 npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail",
        "build:aot": "npm run build:aot:prod",
        "build:aot:dev": "cross-env BUILD_AOT=1 npm run build:dev",
        "build:dev": "rm -rf .dist/ && npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.dev.js --mode development --progress --profile --trace-deprecation",
        "build:docker": "npm run build:prod && docker build -t angular-webpack-starter:latest .",
        "build:prod": "rm -rf .dist/ && npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail",
        "build": "npm run build:dev",
        "ci:aot": "cross-env BUILD_E2E=1 npm run lint && npm run test:ci && npm run build:aot && npm run e2e",
        "ci:jit": "cross-env BUILD_E2E=1 npm run lint && npm run test:ci && npm run build:prod && npm run e2e",
        "ci:nobuild": "npm run lint && npm test:ci && npm run e2e",
        "ci:testall": "cross-env BUILD_E2E=1 npm run lint && npm run test:ci && npm run build:prod && npm run e2e && npm run build:aot && npm run e2e",
        "ci:travis": "cross-env BUILD_E2E=1 npm run lint && npm run test:ci && npm run build:aot && npm run e2e:travis",
        "ci": "npm run ci:testall",
        "clean:all": "npm run rimraf -- doc coverage dist compiled webpack-cache",
        "clean:cache": "npm run rimraf -- webpack-cache",
        "clean:aot": "npm run rimraf -- compiled",
        "clean:dist": "npm run rimraf -- dist",
        "clean:install": "npm set progress=false && npm install",
        "clean": "npm cache verify && npm run rimraf -- node_modules doc coverage dist compiled webpack-cache",
        "docker": "docker",
        "docs": "npm run typedoc -- --options typedoc.json --exclude '**/*.spec.ts' ./src/",
        "docs:compodoc": "compodoc -p tsconfig.json",
        "docs:compodoc:serve": "compodoc -p tsconfig.json -s",
        "docs:compodoc:serve:watch": "compodoc -p tsconfig.json -s -w",
        "e2e:live": "npm-run-all -p -r server:prod:ci protractor:live",
        "e2e:travis": "npm-run-all -p -r server:prod:ci protractor:delay",
        "e2e": "npm-run-all -p -r server:prod:ci protractor",
        "lint": "npm run tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
        "node": "node",
        "postinstall": "npm run webdriver:update",
        "postversion": "git push && git push --tags",
        "preclean:install": "npm run clean",
        "preversion": "npm test",
        "protractor": "protractor",
        "protractor:delay": "sleep 3 && npm run protractor",
        "protractor:live": "protractor --elementExplorer",
        "rimraf": "rimraf",
        "server:dev:hmr": "npm run server:dev -- --hot --hotOnly",
        "server:aot:dev": "cross-env BUILD_AOT=1 npm run server:dev",
        "server:dev": "npm run webpack serve --config config/webpack.dev.js --open --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/",
        "server:prod": "http-server dist -c-1 --cors",
        "server:prod:ci": "http-server dist -p 3000 -c-1 --cors",
        "server": "npm run server:dev",
        "start:prod:hmr": "cross-env ANGULAR_CONF_FILE=./config.prod.json npm run server:dev:hmr",
        "start:hmr": "npm run server:dev:hmr",
        "start": "npm run server:dev",
        "start:aot": "npm run server:aot:dev",
        "test": "karma start",
        "test:sonar": "npm run lint && cross-env SONAR_QUBE=1 karma start",
        "test:ci": "karma start --single-run --browsers ChromeTravisCi",
        "tslint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\" --project tsconfig.json",
        "typedoc": "typedoc",
        "version": "npm run build",
        "watch:dev:hmr": "npm run watch:dev -- --hot",
        "watch:dev": "npm run build:dev -- --watch",
        "watch:aot:dev": "npm run build:aot:dev -- --watch",
        "watch:prod": "npm run build:prod -- --watch",
        "watch:aot:prod": "npm run build:aot:prod -- --watch",
        "watch:test": "npm run test -- --auto-watch --no-single-run",
        "watch": "npm run watch:dev",
        "webdriver-manager": "node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager",
        "webdriver:start": "node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager start",
        "webdriver:update": "node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update",
        "webpack-dev-server": "node --max_old_space_size=20148 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
        "webpack": "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js",
        "profile": "webpack --env production --profile --json > stats.json",
        "bundle-report": "webpack-bundle-analyzer -m static stats.json",
        "postbuild": "npm run purgecss",
        "purgecss": "purgecss --css dist/*.css --content dist/index.html dist/*.js -o dist/"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^16.1.0",
        "@angular/common": "^16.1.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^16.1.0",
        "@angular/core": "^16.1.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^16.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.1.0",
        "@angular/router": "^16.1.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.1.4",
        "@angular/cli": "~16.1.4",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.1.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
        "karma": "~6.4.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
        "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
        "typescript": "~5.1.3",
        "@ngtools/webpack": "^16.1.4",
        "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.41",
        "@types/node": "^20.4.2",
        "@types/uglify-js": "^3.17.1",
        "@types/webpack": "^5.28.1",
        "add-asset-html-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.0",
        "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
        "assets-webpack-plugin": "^7.1.1",
        "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
        "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
        "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
        "exports-loader": "^4.0.0",
        "expose-loader": "^4.1.0",
        "find-root": "^1.1.0",
        "gh-pages": "^5.0.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
        "imports-loader": "^4.0.1",
        "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^3.0.1",
        "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.5",
        "karma-remap-coverage": "^0.1.5",
        "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.4.0",
        "karma-webpack": "^5.0.0",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.6",
        "node-sass": "^9.0.0",
        "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
        "optimize-js-plugin": "^0.0.4",
        "parse5": "^7.1.2",
        "protractor": "^7.0.0",
        "purgecss": "^5.0.0",
        "purgecss-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0",
        "raw-loader": "^4.0.2",
        "replace-in-file-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.6",
        "rimraf": "^5.0.1",
        "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
        "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.8",
        "sass-loader": "^13.3.2",
        "save-dev": "^0.0.1-security",
        "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.5",
        "source-map-loader": "^4.0.1",
        "string-replace-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
        "to-string-loader": "^1.2.0",
        "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
        "tslib": "^2.6.0",
        "tslint": "^6.1.3",
        "tslint-loader": "^3.5.4",
        "typedoc": "^0.24.8",
        "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
        "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
        "webpack": "^5.88.1",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.9.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
        "webpack-dev-middleware": "^6.1.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1",
        "webpack-inline-manifest-plugin": "^4.0.1",
        "webpack-merge": "^5.9.0"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": ">= 8.0.0",
        "npm": ">= 5"
    }
}
```

Here is my webpack.common.js

```
const helpers = require('./helpers');

// Try the environment variable, otherwise use root
const ASSET_PATH = process.env.ASSET_PATH || '/';

/**
 * Webpack Plugins
 *
 * problem with copy-webpack-plugin
 */
const DefinePlugin = require('webpack/lib/DefinePlugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlElementsPlugin = require('./html-elements-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const WebpackInlineManifestPlugin = require('webpack-inline-manifest-plugin');
const ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin = require('script-ext-html-webpack-plugin');
const AngularCompilerPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AngularCompilerPlugin;
// const AotPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AotPlugin;
// const ModuleReplacementPlugins = require('./module-replacements');
const buildUtils = require('./build-utils');
const path = require("path");

/**
 * Webpack configuration
 *
 * See: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/
 */
module.exports = function (options) {
    const isProd = options.env === 'production';
    const isDev = options.env === 'development';
    // const configFolder = '../src/configs/' + (options.cfgFolder ? options.cfgFolder : ''); // Will pick the partner config file else the default config file
    // const APP_CONFIG = require(configFolder);

    const METADATA = Object.assign({}, buildUtils.DEFAULT_METADATA, options.metadata || {});

    const ngcWebpackConfig = buildUtils.ngcWebpackSetup(isProd, METADATA);
    const supportES2015 = buildUtils.supportES2015(METADATA.tsConfigPath);

    const entry = {
        polyfills: './src/polyfills.browser.ts',
        main: './src/main.browser.ts'
    };
    
    Object.assign(ngcWebpackConfig.plugin, {
        tsConfigPath: METADATA.tsConfigPath,
        mainPath: entry.main
    });

    return {
        /**
         * The entry point for the bundle
         * Our Angular.js app
         *
         * See: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#entry
         */
        entry: entry,

        /**
         * Options affecting the resolving of modules.
         *
         * See: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/
         */
        resolve: {
            mainFields: [...(supportES2015 ? ['es2015'] : []), 'browser', 'module', 'main'],

            /**
             * An array of extensions that should be used to resolve modules.
             *
             * See: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-extensions
             */
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json'],

            /**
             * An array of directory names to be resolved to the current directory
             */
            modules: [helpers.root('src'), helpers.root('node_modules')],

            /**
             * Add support for lettable operators.
             *
             * For existing codebase a refactor is required.
             * All rxjs operator imports (e.g. `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'` or `import { map } from `rxjs/operator/map'`
             * must change to `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'` (note that all operators are now under that import.
             * Additionally some operators have changed to to JS keyword constraints (do => tap, catch => catchError)
             *
             * Remember to use the `pipe()` method to chain operators, this functinoally makes lettable operators similar to
             * the old operators usage paradigm.
             *
             * For more details see:
             * https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md#build-and-treeshaking
             *
             * If you are not planning on refactoring your codebase (or not planning on using imports from `rxjs/operators`
             * comment out this line.
             *
             * BE AWARE that not using lettable operators will probably result in significant payload added to your bundle.
             */
            // alias: buildUtils.rxjsAlias(supportES2015)
            alias: {
                "@app": path.resolve(helpers.root('src'), 'app'),
                "@configs": path.resolve(helpers.root('src'), 'configs')
            },
        },

        /**
         * Options affecting the normal modules.
         *
         * See: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/
         */
        module: {
            rules: [
                ...ngcWebpackConfig.loaders,
                /**
                 * To string and css loader support for *.css files (from Angular components)
                 * Returns file content as string
                 *
                 */
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'],
                    exclude: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
                },

                /**
                 * To string and sass loader support for *.scss files (from Angular components)
                 * Returns compiled css content as string
                 *
                 */
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    use: [
                        isDev ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader'
                        },
                        // {
                        //     loader: 'postcss-loader'
                        // },
                        {
                            loader: 'sass-loader'
                        }
                    ],
                    exclude: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
                },

                /**
                 * Raw loader support for *.html
                 * Returns file content as string
                 *
                 * See: https://github.com/webpack/raw-loader
                 */
                {
                    test: /\.html$/,
                    use: 'raw-loader',
                    exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')]
                },

                /**
                 * File loader for supporting images, for example, in CSS files.
                 */
                {
                    test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
                    use: 'file-loader'
                },

                /* File loader for supporting fonts, for example, in CSS files.
                */
                {
                    test: /\.(eot|woff2?|svg|ttf)([\?]?.*)$/,
                    use: 'file-loader'
                }
            ]
        },

        /**
         * Add additional plugins to the compiler.
         *
         * See: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/plugins/
         */
        plugins: [
            /**
             * Plugin: DefinePlugin
             * Description: Define free variables.
             * Useful for having development builds with debug logging or adding global constants.
             *
             * Environment helpers
             *
             * See: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/
             */
            // NOTE: when adding more properties make sure you include them in custom-typings.d.ts
            new DefinePlugin({
                ENV: JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
                HMR: METADATA.HMR,
                AOT: METADATA.AOT,
                'process.env.ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
                'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
                'process.env.HMR': METADATA.HMR,
                'process.env.ASSET_PATH': JSON.stringify(ASSET_PATH)
            }),

            /**
             * Plugin: CopyWebpackPlugin
             * Description: Copy files and directories in webpack.
             *
             * Copies project static assets.
             *
             * See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin
             */
            new CopyWebpackPlugin(
                // [{ from: 'src/assets', to: 'assets' }]
                // isProd ? { ignore: ['mock-data/**/*'] } : undefined
                {
                    patterns: [
                        {from: path.resolve('src/assets'), to:'assets'}
                    ]
                }
            ),

            /*
            * Plugin: HtmlWebpackPlugin
            * Description: Simplifies creation of HTML files to serve your webpack bundles.
            * This is especially useful for webpack bundles that include a hash in the filename
            * which changes every compilation.
            *
            * See: https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
            */
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: 'src/index.html',
                title: METADATA.title,
                chunksSortMode: function (a, b) {
                    const entryPoints = ['inline', 'polyfills', 'sw-register', 'styles', 'vendor', 'main'];
                    return entryPoints.indexOf(a.names[0]) - entryPoints.indexOf(b.names[0]);
                },
                metadata: METADATA,
                gtmKey: '', // Google Tag Manager key
                inject: 'body',
                xhtml: true,
                minify: isProd
                    ? {
                        caseSensitive: true,
                        collapseWhitespace: true,
                        keepClosingSlash: true
                    }
                    : false
            }),

            /**
             * Plugin: ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin
             * Description: Enhances html-webpack-plugin functionality
             * with different deployment options for your scripts including:
             *
             * See: https://github.com/numical/script-ext-html-webpack-plugin
             */
            new ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin({
                sync: /inline|polyfills|vendor/,
                defaultAttribute: 'async',
                preload: [/polyfills|vendor|main/],
                prefetch: [/chunk/]
            }),

            /**
             * Plugin: HtmlElementsPlugin
             * Description: Generate html tags based on javascript maps.
             *
             * If a publicPath is set in the webpack output configuration, it will be automatically added to
             * href attributes, you can disable that by adding a "=href": false property.
             * You can also enable it to other attribute by settings "=attName": true.
             *
             * The configuration supplied is map between a location (key) and an element definition object (value)
             * The location (key) is then exported to the template under then htmlElements property in webpack configuration.
             *
             * Example:
             *  Adding this plugin configuration
             *  new HtmlElementsPlugin({
             *    headTags: { ... }
             *  })
             *
             *  Means we can use it in the template like this:
             *  <%= webpackConfig.htmlElements.headTags %>
             *
             * Dependencies: HtmlWebpackPlugin
             */
            new HtmlElementsPlugin({
                headTags: require('./head-config.common')
            }),

            new AngularCompilerPlugin(ngcWebpackConfig.plugin),

            /**
             * Plugin: WebpackInlineManifestPlugin
             * Inline Webpack's manifest.js in index.html
             *
             * https://github.com/almothafar/webpack-inline-manifest-plugin
             */
            new WebpackInlineManifestPlugin(),

            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: isDev ? '[name].css' : '[name].[hash].css',
                chunkFilename: isDev ? '[id].css' : '[id].[hash].css'
            }),

           

            // new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
            //     /src\/configs\/config\.json/,
            //     partnerConfigPath
            // ),

            // new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/(.*)APP_TARGET(\.*)/, function(resource) {
            //     resource.request = resource.request.replace(/APP_TARGET/, `${appTarget}`);
            // }),

            // new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/(.*)LANDING_MODULE(\.*)/, function(resource) {
            //     resource.request = resource.request.replace(/LANDING_MODULE/, `${appTarget}`);
            // }),

            // ...ModuleReplacementPlugins.pluginList(options)
        ],

        /**
         * Include polyfills or mocks for various node stuff
         * Description: Node configuration
         *
         * See: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/
         */
        node: {
            global: true,
            crypto: 'empty',
            process: true,
            module: false,
            clearImmediate: false,
            setImmediate: false
        },

        stats: {
            errorDetails: true,
            children: true
         },
    };
};
```

Can someone help me with this issue?